# How to accelerate time ranged query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL data table with around 30 million records, one of the fields is create_time, which is a timestamp.

I want to get the count of records in a specified time range, and use unique keywords to get the unique user count.

The SQL statement is:

```
select count(distinct owner_id) from code_orange_checkpointrecord 
where create_time between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-01-30 23:59:59';
```

But the query is very slow. I tried to create an index on create_time, but the result is a lot slower.

I think I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Try with an index on (create_time,owner_id).  If you need more help, please update your question to show output (as text, not images) of `show create table code_orange_checkpointrecord` and `explain select ...` for the different queries/indexes you tried

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "code_orange_checkpointrecord"; for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The precise query you showed us will be accelerated by this multi-column index.

```
CREATE INDEX create_owner  
    ON code_orange_checkpointrecord (create_time, owner_id);
```

And, by the way, it's best to avoid `BETWEEN` for time ranges. Use this instead to get all the records for January.  `23:59:59` might not be the precise last timestamp in the month, so it's better to use `<` and the first timestamp you don't want.

```
where create_time >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' 
  and create_time <  '2023-02-01 00:00:00';
```